# Pass the id of listview on click to next page in ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }

    if(window.StatusBar) {

      StatusBar.styleDefault();

    }

  });

})

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider


  .state('first', {

    url: '/1',

    templateUrl: 'templates/first.html',

    controller:'firstCtrl'

  })

  .state('next', {

    url: '/2',

    templateUrl: 'templates/next.html',

    controller:'nextCtrl'

  })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/1");

})

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = [

    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 },
    { id: 4 },
    { id: 5 },
    { id: 6 },
    { id: 7 },
    { id: 8 },
    { id: 9 },
    { id: 10 },
    { id: 11 },
    { id: 12 },
    { id: 13 },
    { id: 14 },
    { id: 15 },
    { id: 16 },
    { id: 17 },
    { id: 18 },
    { id: 19 },
    { id: 20 }
  ]

$scope.selectedElem = function(item){

$scope.itemid=item.id;

}

})

app.controller('nextCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.input =''; 

});
```

In first.html

```
<ion-view title="Ionic List View">

  <ion-content>

      <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" ui-sref="next" ng-model="item" ng-

click="selectedElem(item.id)">
      Item {{item.id}}

      </ion-item>

  </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

In next.html

```
<ion-view title="Selected List View">

  <ion-content>

  <ion-item>

    Item{{ itemId }}


  </ion-item>

  </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use [query params](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#basic-parameters) to set the next view. You'd end up with something like the following:

**State**

```
.state('item', {
    url: '/item/:itemId',
    templateUrl: 'templates/item-detail.html',
    controller:'ItemCtrl'
})
```

**Item List View**

```
<ion-view title="Ionic List View">    
  <ion-content>    
      <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" ng-model="item" ui-sref="item({itemId: item.id})">
      Item {{item.id}}    
      </ion-item>    
  </ion-content>    
</ion-view>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('ItemCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.itemId = $stateParams.itemId;
});
```

**Item Detail View**

```
<ion-view title="Selected List View">    
  <ion-content>    
    <ion-item>    
      Item{{ itemId }}        
    </ion-item>    
  </ion-content>    
</ion-view>
```

What I've done is:

1. Redefined your state to take an `itemId` url param
2. Redefined your `ng-repeat` to generate to proper url to the new `item` state with the correct `itemId`
3. Redefined your controller to take a dependency on `$stateParams` which has the values of all params passed to the state.
4. Set the `item` template to read the id from `$scope`